# Vercel server is running fine client is not

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, vercel

I have deployed a repo on vercel
it is a repo which has a client folder which contains a react app
and a server folder which contains an express node app

I want to make it so that I host these on only vercel app I dont want a seperate frontend and backend app in my vercel

So I have this vercel.json file

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "server/index.ts",
      "use": "@now/node"
    },
    {
      "src": "client/package.json",
      "use": "@vercel/static-build"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/api/(.*)",
      "dest": "/server/index.ts"
    },
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "/client/public/$1"
    }
  ]
}
```

The thing is that wheneevr I go to /api routes my server works perfectly but my client does not whenevr i go to / I dont see homepage

heres link to repo if you want to see structure in detail : https://www.github.com/marsian83/monohost

Comment: Shouldn't the client "dest" be `"dest": "/client/dist/$1"`. AFAIK Vite's default build directory is named "dist" and "public" is for static assets.

Comment: doesnt help, still same